# change video playback rate in android

Tags: android, android-video-player, android-audiorecord

i am developing a video recorder which should change the frequency and pitch of the sound only. video should play with the same rate. I used the Soundpool library to change rate of sound in android but it says it only works for audio files. Meanwhile for video recording i am using  Mediarecorder library. I used setAudioSamplingRate but it just alters the frequency not pitch of sound. Can you tell me the solution.

Regards